# Cannot delete owned folder via FTP

Tags: permissions, python, ftp

I know this has been asked many time but I can't find a solution.

so I use `vsftpd` and `FileZilla` as a client

in `/var/www/`

```
drwxrwsr-x+  8 myuser ftpusers 4.0K Sep  2 10:37 html
```

in `/var/www/html/`

```
drwxrwxrwx   3 myuser ftpusers 4.0K Sep  2 10:38 directory
```

I cannot delete directory although I own it

FileZilla log says

```
rmdir /www/html/directory: failure
```

I already tried 777 on the HTML folder but in vain. Although it works simply on the command line.

After changing the python script from `os.mkdir` to `os.system("mkdir")`, the problem appears to be gone, but yet I am interested if anyone could give me a clue.

```
/var/www$ getfacl html
# file: html
# owner: myuser
# group: ftpusers
user::rwx
group::rwx
group:admin:rwx
group:synchronizer:rwx
mask::rwx
other::--x
```

Comment: The permissions depend on how you are connected via ftp (from the question it is unclear if you are logged in with *your* account, or using the ftp daemon's permissions).

Comment: well yes connected with my account, If I create a dir, it is created with the exact same permissions, and I can remove it...this is really a odd case

Comment: can you please do `getfacl html` and show us output of it

Answer (score 1):

In your directory listing

```
drwxrwsr-x+  8 myuser ftpusers 4.0K Sep  2 10:37 html
```

the "+" indicates that there are *extended permissions* on the `html` directory.  When you use a runtime call such as `os.mkdir` rather than a shell command with `os.system`, the two may first check using [`access`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/faccessat.2.html) if you are allowed to remove this directory — or they may not (relying upon the operating system to decide).

The Debian wiki [*Permissions*](https://wiki.debian.org/Permissions) mentions this possibility:

> The last column is the **`+`** sign. You are unlikely to see it while listing a directory now (it will appear empty), but it means that extended access rules are in effect, so the *file's real permissions are not only what the file access mode says* - you can read about ACL below in this howto.

Your problem might be (for instance) that an ACL prohibits deletion from something running with a given group-id (where the ftp process is running with its own group), or the access check might notice if the ftp daemon is running with a different *real user*.

Further reading:

- [What does a + mean at the end of the permissions from ls -l?](https://serverfault.com/questions/227852/what-does-a-mean-at-the-end-of-the-permissions-from-ls-l)
- [What does the @ mean on the output of “ls” on OS X' terminal?](https://superuser.com/questions/155458/what-does-the-mean-on-the-output-of-ls-on-os-x-terminal)

Comment: but my ACL are always allowing , not denying access (I added theem in the question

Comment: also the issue is not in python, but with filezilla..python does not add any acl to the created directory and does not change the usual acl...